# Session State strange behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms, state

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 webforms app that sits on two webservers (IIS) and is load balanced via a content switch with sticky affinity.  I have a page that puts data into a session variable, javascript opens a new browser window, and in the page_load event of that page, i retrieve that session variable and display the data.

the problem is that in all versions of IE, about 7 times out of ten, no data is displayed.  If i keep refreshing the newly opened window, it will eventually display the data.  I can verify that before that browser window is opened, the session variable is valid.

An additional twist is that firefox doesn't have this issue.  The data is displayed 100% of the time the first time.  The problem is we don't (officially) support firefox.

We don't have access to any third party datastore such as MSSQL or MySQL, so storing session data there isn't an option.  Plus the ability to cache the data client side isn't practical and in some cases not an option.

This doesn't happen locally or in our test environment (which isn't load balanced), so i'm truly baffled.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: All versions of IE?  I'd expect this in IE8 since each browser tab/window creates a new session, but prior to IE8 I would have expected it to work.

Answer (score 3):

What session store provider are you using? InProc, StateServer? It *sounds* like you're using InProc. If so, since you don't have access to a DB, switching to StateServer may be your answer.

Here's an article about [ASP.NET load balancing and ASP.NET state server](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/11/ASPNET-load-balancing-and-ASPNET-state-server-%28aspnet_state%29.aspx) that may help you.

Comment: But why would it work fine in firefox but not IE all things being equal?

Comment: Possibly due to the way the load balancers are handling server affinity (maybe ip, cookie, or response header based) and whether or not the different browsers pass that information back to the server from a new window.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm going to take a look at the state server option and let you know how that works.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you are using sticky session/affinity. Can you confirm that your load balancer is looking at HTTP cookies (not only IP address) to determine stickiness, since IP addresses can change during a single session (e.g. docking a laptop between a wired and wireless network).

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that we're using port 443 and SSL, so we have to use IP.

Comment: then that might be your problem. You have to use the state server mentioned in the other answer.